# Fault on CortexM0+ From LDRH Instruction

Tags: c, gcc, embedded, fault, cortex-m

I have a codebase that runs fine on the M3 architecture and am porting some code to the M0+. I am getting faults and I cannot figure out why. The exact micro I am on is the KL36Z128 (Freescale). I am using ARM-GCC-2013-Q3 release for my toolchain.

So here is the C code (it's for parsing packets as they come in so once I get enough data I just start picking out what I need to fill out the command structures):

state->cmd = *((U16*)&din[15]);  // the codebase has 'legacy' type definitions

The assembly generated is:

0x4250  <+0x0014>         adds  r1, #15

0x4252  <+0x0016>         ldrh  r1, [r1, #0]  <--- Faulting instruction!

0x4254  <+0x0018>         strh  r1, [r0, #2]

And the register values are at the time of the fault are:

r0 = 0x1ffff2cc
r1 = 0x1ffffad8

I have no idea what is happening here - this seems pretty straightforward assembly. And the addressing seems OK. The Freescale datasheet says that RAM is banked with 2 sections:

SRAM_L: (0x20000000-1KB) to 0x20000000    (so it's lower section is 1/4 of the total SRAM)

SRAM_H: 0x20000000 to (0x20000000+3KB)

I originally thought that maybe something was amiss with the code being generated and what instructions can be used to access memory in the different banks - but I came up empty.

Also, the 'din' value is defined in the functions parameter list as: const U8 *din

Any thoughts?

Comment: Is `din` of type array of `uint8_t`? In that case you are violating alignment rules!

Comment: yes, the declaration in the parameter list is  "const U8 *din". Where in this codebase, U8 is mapped to uint8_t.

Comment: So you program invokes undefined behavior. You are accessing an `uint8t_t` object as an `uint16_t` object. Cortex-M0+ does not support unaligned access and an attempt to perform an unaligned access raises an HardFault.

Comment: Yep. I just looked it up - didn't know that obviously. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Ouah answered the question - but I have no idea how to mark his answer as "accepted".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
state->cmd = *((U16*)&din[15]);
```

The `*` operation performs an unaligned access as `din[15]` element is of type `uint8_t` but is accessed as a `uint16_t` (or `U16`) object . Cortex-M0 / M0+ does not support unaligned access and any attempt to perform an unaligned access raises an HardFault.

http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0497a/BABFAIGG.html

To fix your program, access `din` elements as `uint8_t` objects:

```
 state->cmd = (din[16] << 8) | din[15];
```